# Software that converts from legal description text?

Tags: convert, free-software, land-survey, metes-and-bounds, legal-description

Is there software that takes legal description text as input for conversion to some computer friendly GIS format? For example:

```
Those portions of the North Half of the Southeast Quarter and
the Northeast Quarter of the Southwest Quarter of Section 5,
T.13S., R.4E., S.B.B.&M., according to United States Government
Survey approved February 24, 1876 described as follows:

Beginning at a 1 1/2 inch iron pipe having coordinates
Y = 329,169.63, X = 1,895,486.55, set for the center of said
Section 5, thence along the East line of said Southwest
Quarter, S.4°11'18"W., 24.65 feet; thence S.56°02'45"E.,
...
All bearings and coordinates are referred to the California
Coordinate System, Zone 6.
```

More specifically, open source software.

Assuming that info that would be broad enough such as "S.B.B.&M." & "California
Coordinate System, Zone 6." can be addressed but realizing that a reference to something like a specific adjacent parcel recorded locally would require manual effort.

Comment: Not that I've seen. The problem is a 'legal' description can contain just about any phrases and use names that are not contained in the data: e.g. follow the westernmost boundary of Farmer Fred's property to the creek. It's *really* painful I know but a bit of real intelligence is required to turn legal description into a shape.

Comment: I agree. It's hard enough to decipher the above description as a human, let alone trying to program a computer to figure it out automatically...

Comment: No such *free* software exists that I was able to find, and I looked pretty hard because this is 95% of my current consulting work. I know of two commercially available packages that do it. One via a module in their software that connects over the web to a service on one of their servers. I was not terribly impressed with the results/interface for corrections. If you have a clean, consistent description it was great. But those are few and far between. Part of why it's a service like it is though is because they are constantly updating/improving it.